# Detecting UPX programmatically

Tags: c, windows, packing, upx

I'm trying to figure out how to detect whether a binary has been compressed with UPX. I am using a simple CRC to detect whether my app was in any way changed and if the CRC failed on the size due to a packer I would like to detect that as OK.

Right now I am starting with UPX.

So, is there any marker on the binary? are there any specific JMP or other instructions that I should search?
This will mainly be tested in Windows, but in the future I might add it to Linux as well.

Any help (and code) is appreciated.

ADDED:

I found that in the 10 binaries I checked the

`AddressOfEntryPoint

Import Directory RVA

Resouce Directory RVA`

either point to UPX or have an offset that is set by UPX. Any information on this?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at UPX unpacker source-code, i am sure an algorithm for UPX detection should be there

Comment: Already did and it's a mess to put it mildly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try checking the section names of the executable.  UPX changes them to UPX0, UPX1, UPX2, I believe.

Comment: This method is unfortunately not reliable. The sections of some (packed/encrypted) images are renamed to "standard"/"traditional" sections names. The names of the sections is never "interpreted" by the Loader. The names of the sections are sometimes even missing (aka removed) by some tools.

Comment: @mox, this response is specific to the UPX packer.  Running additional packers or obfuscators may further modify the section names; however, by default, the UPX packer will change the section names described above.

Answer (score 2):

Download `upx` source code from [UPX Homepage](http://upx.sf.net) and open `src/p_w32pe.cpp` file; the function you are looking for is;

```
int PackW32Pe::canUnpack()
```

This function checks if the file is compressed with win32 upx.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I am having a hard time following that code with the different objects and their constructors. For a win32 it calls `PackW32Pe` (in an .h file) but that in turns creates another call, etc... I'm a C programmer and objects are not very strong with me. Any specific you might add from reading that code? Thanks again